# How to insert values to table where id equal to another table

Tags: sql

```
      user         user_time
    ---------     -----------
      id             id
     first_name     user_id        
     last_name      time_start
```

How do i insert to user_time table where user_id is equal to user Id from first table.

Here are my codes but returns error

```
    INSERT INTO user_time(time_start) 
    WHERE user_time.user_id = user.id
```

Comment: You have not specified which RDBMS you're using.  Without that, it is hard to know what functions are available for use.  Time handling is one of the areas that varies most between SQL systems.

Answer (score 1):

Probably some variant on:

```
INSERT INTO User_Time(User_ID, Time_Start)
    SELECT User_ID, NOW
      FROM User
```

You need the correct function in place of `NOW` — since you've not specified which RDBMS you're using, it is hard to know what to use.  And you can specify any appropriate value instead of `NOW` as you wish.

If you have appropriate defaults set up, you might be able to use just this, which circumvents the issues of how to specify the time:

```
INSERT INTO User_Time(User_ID)
    SELECT User_ID
      FROM User
```